# Did anyone notice Audio Converter Services changed internally on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, core-audio

My app is using Audio Converter Services to convert audio from 44.1 khz to 48 khz (16 bit linear mono), using AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer.

After upgrading iOS to 11.0 (or maybe 11.4) the audio contains "noises" that are cause by the callback returning samples with the value of zero at the "edges" of the buffer (not sure if first or last sample)

Does anyone know or noticed any change? It has been working fine for years, and still works fine on devices that run iOS 9.x

This is my setup:

```
// prepare the formats
// origin
AudioStreamBasicDescription  originFormat = {0};
FillOutASBDForLPCM(originFormat, 44100.00, 1, sizeof(SInt16)*8, sizeof(SInt16)*8, false, false, false);
originFormat.mFormatFlags |= kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
originFormat.mReserved = 0;

// destination
AudioStreamBasicDescription  destFormat = {0};
FillOutASBDForLPCM(destFormat, 48000.0, 1, sizeof(SInt16)*8, sizeof(SInt16)*8, false, false, false);
destFormat.mFormatFlags |= kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
destFormat.mReserved = 0;


// create a converter
AudioConverterRef audioConverter;
AudioConverterNew(&originFormat, &destFormat, &audioConverter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that converting between sample rates used to be more tolerant to missing data on the edges of the buffer.
For example, if you convert a buffer of 1024 frames, and need all of those to be converted to a new sample rate, but never provided samples before or after the buffer, apple used to round the numbers so that the noise is minimal.

However, starting iOS 11.4 (or so), the first frame of the converted buffer is very close to zero (probably because the converter is looking for samples before the first sample and can't find any)

The fix was to provide some extra samples to the buffer in question. For example, to convert the 1024 buffer, I sent the converter about 100 samples before and after that range (1224 in total), then read the result starting from sample number 100. Once I did this for every buffer, the result was clean